# RESTful way to accept a choice

Tags: rest

I have a simple api, that works like this:

1. A user creates a request ( `POST /requests`)
2. Another user retrieves all requests ( `GET /requests`)
3. Then adds an offer to a request ( `POST /requests/123/offers`)
4. Original user can now see all the offers being made for the request (`GET /requests/123/offers`)

What i want to do, is allow the inital user to accept an request, but I can't figure out the best way to do it RESTfuly.

Should I do it with the PATCH verb? Like `PATCH /requests/123` and require that the patch body contain a valid offer id?

Comment: I'd say that POST would be appropriate for accepting a request, you could be using PUT for creating requests and offers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Accepting an offer five times should have the same effect as accepting it once. It is idempotent. So it should be a PUT.

You might want to consider choosing a different name for your "requests."  When I do `GET /requests/123`, I request a response that is a request?  This could be a little confusing for clients.

Additionally, try to avoid nesting your resource identifiers.  That can create problems for you later.  An offer doesn't really have to be "underneath" the corresponding request.  What happens when you later want to have offers corresponding to multiple requests?

> A good rule of thumb is, if you would consider "Gizmo" an entity in an [entity-relationship model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model), it should be a root-level URI, like  in `GET /gizmos/17`, not `GET /widgets/54/gizmos/17`. A common mistake is to say "Every Gizmo has exactly one related Widget, so I should nest Gizmo URIs as extensions of Widget URIs."

Below I have a suggestion for how the operations would look.  You may want to replace some of the ID references with URIs instead, but that's up to you.

```
POST /requests            --->   201 Created
                                 Location: /requests/123

GET /requests             --->   200 OK
                                 [
                                     {
                                         "requestId": 123,
                                         "offersUri": "/offers?requestId=123",
                                         ...
                                     },
                                     ...
                                 ]

POST /offers              --->   201 Created
{                                Location: /offers/456
    "requestId": 123,
    "amount": 300,
    ...
}

GET /offers?requestId=123 --->   200 OK
                                 [
                                     {
                                         "requestId": 123,
                                         "amount": 300,
                                         ...
                                     }
                                 ]

PUT /offers/456/approval   --->  204 No Content
PUT /offers/456/approval   --->  204 No Content
PUT /offers/456/approval   --->  204 No Content
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning deeply nesting identifiers. This is too common of a mistake when people are beginners at REST architecture.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer seems the way to go. The only question I have is about offer list. How would I go about providing an easy way to retrieve all offers for a request? Should there be an url parameter for filtering in `GET /offers?request=123` or should i provide a parameter to embedd this data in request `GET /request/123?embedded=true`, which would replace offerIds with the actual offers?

Comment: @JanisPeisenieks `GET /offers?requestId=123` seems sensible to me. Avoid your latter suggestion, `GET /request/123?embedded=true`. A resource should link to its related resources - not embed them. In fact, you might even consider making the request resource look like this instead of what I suggested above: `{ "requestId": 123, "offersUri": "/offers?requestId=123" }`

Comment: Thanks! Your response has been most helpful!

Comment: @JanisPeisenieks I actually edited my answer to use this `offersUri` approach instead.

Comment: I preferred the previous design where the offers list was part of the requests GET data. I can't see a reason to have a separate resource for request offers in addition to request info, but I don't have all the details about the application.

Comment: @protonfish The reasoning is that, if there is already a way to query offers by the request they correspond to, it can be used as a link in the request resource, rather than being duplicated there.

Comment: I wouldn't duplicate it - I'd use one or the other. But I worry that having them separate will mean that you will frequently have two calls when you really want one. If the main request information is small, there would not be much extra overhead. If I had to pick the second most common mistake for REST beginners, it would be making the resources too atomic. I just witnessed a production app fail due to service bloat: there were 20 calls on the login screen alone. Services should be designed to the needs of the app, IMO.

Comment: @protonfish Optimization and proper conceptual design are not necessarily the same thing. From the question: "I can't figure out the best way to do it RESTfuly." Providing `GET /offers/456` and `GET /requests/123` as two ways to get at the resource `/offers/456` could be an optimization, but I wouldn't say it's great conceptual design. The offer is not conceptually part of the request. I 100% agree with you from the performance point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the nature of the Acceptance.

If Acceptance is a simple attribute of an offer, I would POST the Offer with the Acceptance set to True.

If the Acceptance is more complex and therefore a resource in its own right, I would PUT an Acceptance into the offer (`PUT /requests/123/offers/acceptance`).

If there exists such a thing as a rejection, or a request for offer clarification, I might consider the relevant resource to be a Response, not an Acceptance, and PUT that (`put /requests/123/offers/response`).

Comment: Not worthy of a downvote, but you seem to be putting a lot of action data in the URI which violates the separation of identification and transformation principle of REST.

Comment: I fail to see how treating a Response as a separate document or resource constitutes encoding action into the URI.  The options I offered (in the event that a response is modeled as a complex object) are Acceptance and Response, not *Accept* and *Respond* (which would suffer from confusing action with item).  In fact, in a formal RFQ system it's entirely possible that the Response should be modeled separately.

Comment: I guess I see REST as a combination of resources and representations, and your model only seems to use resources. If the state of an offer (accepted/rejected) is not a representation, I don't know what is.

Comment: As I stated (and I think rather clearly) a Response can either be considered part of the state of a resource *OR* a separate resource itself (if it contains information about the responder, the RFQ reviewers, the terms, and offer deadline, etc).  That decision ought to be guided by the actual statement of the problem to be solved, which is known only to the OP.  In any event, neither option necessarily implies coding procedural action into the URI.